# URL parameters on page_load c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-parameters, pageload

Is it possible to set URL parameters on page_load?

For example, if I have some strings value defined in the code like this:

```
string firstname = "John";
string lastname = "doe";
```

So when I run the application I want the URL to be like localhost:/webform.aspx?firstname=john&lastname="doe" directly.

Comment: Do you mean during debugging, or do you mean during normal production operation? If you mean debugging the project properties has a "Web" tab where you can set it to load a specific page or url.

Comment: During normal production

Answer (score 0):

If you are redirecting to webform.aspx from somewhere (e.g. default.aspx) within your application you'll be able to set these parameters in the corresponding method in default.aspx.cs.
If you are already in the page_load of webform.aspx, you surely can redirect to webform.aspx with additional url parameters, however this possibly creates unnecessary traffic between the webclient accessing your webapp and the server providing your webapp.

If you wan't these parameters to be present so you can use them client side (e.g. in javascript), I'd recommend using HiddenFields and setting the value of those in your page_load method.
If you need these parameters in an other place in the code behind of webform.aspx, I'd recommend storing the values in the session.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! My application is not so heavy, so I think I can use the first recommendation.

Comment: Great! Don't forget to accept my answer so this thread doesn't stay open.